# gaussian elimination of permutation matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a binary sparse matrix **H** of size 600*1200 constructed by concatenating square permutation matrices of size 200, thus sparse matrix have 3 ones in each column and 6 ones in each row. Now am trying to transform the matrix into **reduced echelon form**.
This is my code:

```
    [m,n]=size(H);

for i=1:m 
    ind=find(H(:,i),1,'last');

    if ind<=i
        continue;
    end
    if ind~=i
        temp=H(ind,:);
        H(ind,:)=H(i,:);
        H(i,:)=temp;
    end
    I=find(H(:,i));
    % Guassian elimination
    for j=1:length(I)
        if I(j)~=i
            H(I(j),:)=mod(H(I(j),:)+H(i,:),2);
        end
    end
end
```

But whichever **H** matrix generated, I can't get rid of other entries at 400th column,

how can I fix this, help

Comment: Why not [`rref`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rref.html)?

Comment: Am getting the same problem, thus still 400th column has some entries

Comment: @Engtyma Is it wrong the 400th column to have entries?

Comment: @AnderBiguri , yes. the first 600 columns matrix should be identity matrix,thus 400th column should also have only one entry

Comment: @Engtyma Why should the first 600 columns be the identity matrix? That's not true in general for reduced row echelon form

Comment: I have sparse matrix **H**  of size 600*1200. so I want to do gaus-jordan elimination to get a matrix which is concatenation of 600 * 600 identity matrix and a dense matrix of 600*600. By using the above code or `rref` ,I get the leftmost matrix almost identity except for 400th column. What might be wrong and how to modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Gaussian elimination does not involve rearrangement of columns, the first 600 columns of the resulting matrix will only form the identity matrix if the first 600 columns of the *original* matrix were linearly independent. Otherwise, you are going to have "short" columns with other entries in them, as [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form) shows.

The way your matrix is structured, the first 400 columns are guaranteed to be linearly dependent. Indeed, the sum of the first 200 columns is the all-1 vector, and so is the sum of the columns 201-400. This is why you are seeing these entries in the 400th column.

To create identity matrix on the left you need to rearrange columns. One way, which looks a bit redundant but is very easy to code, is to

1. run your algorithm
2. rearrange columns (it's easy to identify the desired columns after rref)
3. do rref again.

Here is the code that does steps 2-3.

```
for i = 1:m
    j = find(H(i,:),1,'first');
    [H(:,i), H(:,j)] = deal(H(:,j), H(:,i));
end
H = rref(H)
```

---

Sample input into rref:

```
 1     0     1     0     1
 0     1     0     0     1
 1     0     1     1     0
 0     0     0     0     1
```

Output of your code:

```
 1     0     1     1     0
 0     1     0     0     1
 0     0     0     1     1
 0     0     0     0     1
```

After the column swap and second rref:

```
 1     0     0     0     1
 0     1     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     1     0
```